# Special Character Check using java pattern?

Tags: java

Please get me the code for saving a-z,A-Z,0-9 also below mention characters

•   . period
•   , comma
•   ? question mark
•   ! exclamation point
•   - dash ***
•   _ underscore
•   ( ) parentheses
•   : colon
•   ; semicolon
•   $ dollar sign
•   asterisk
•   © copyright symbol
•   ® registered symbol
•   § section symbol
•   @ ampersand
•   / \ forward and back slashes
•   Ó acute character
•   Ç French cedille

please help out...

Comment: Could you give some example, please?

Comment: If you told us what you meant by "special character" you might get more relevant answers.

Answer (score 3):

use \\(four times) for \

Answer (score 0):

here's an example to check email via regex

```
        String fieldValue="allss@homtial.com";
        String expression = "^[a-zA-Z0-9._-+$]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$";
        CharSequence inputStr = fieldValue.trim();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
        boolean match=false;

        if( matcher.matches()){
          match=true;
        }
```

Comment: Although this is a useful example of how to use regular expressions, the actual regex has a number of problems that will cause it to reject valid email addresses. For example: top-level domain names are not required to be 2-4 characters long, and email addresses are allowed to contain many special characters (such as '&', '+') that this regex rejects.

Comment: i didn't see an email address which contain '+' or ''$'before , but if u think emails may contains theses characters i will add them to my regex, but about the top-level domain i think it should be 3 characters long,doesn't it?

Comment: @Don,'\s' means any space in regex.